# NSIS call function once time if at least one section is selected

Tags: function, nsis

I have a function

```
Function installDll

...
EndFunction
```

I have some sections :

- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
- f

I would like call the function installDll once time if at least one of sections { a, b, c, d} is selected.

Comment: Do you need to call your function at the time the component is selected, or simply during the installation of the first selected component?

Comment: simply during the installation of the first selected component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call your function from each concerned section and use a variable as a flag to know if the function has already been called:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"    ;used for ${if} constructs

Section "A"
    Call installDll
SectionEnd

Section "B"
    Call installDll
SectionEnd

Section "C"
    Call installDll
SectionEnd

Section "D"
    Call installDll
SectionEnd

Section "Other"
    ;... do not call the function
SectionEnd

Var instFlag
Function installDll

    ${ifThen} $instFlag = 1 ${|} goto skip ${|}
    StrCpy $instFlag 1

    ;... the rest of your function

    ;the following label is the last statement of the function
    skip:
EndFunction
```

Comment: Thanks ! An other question : I have a section unnamed. Does this section is executed before the others sections or after ?

Comment: @user2084608: The sections are executed in the order they appear in the nsis script and if theu are selected. You could check by using `${debug} 'message'` in the section and a tool like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to listen to the debug messages

Comment: if you are not using `nsdialogs.nsh`, you can define the `${debug}` macro with !define DEBUG `System::Call kernel32::OutputDebugString(ts)`